# SqlDateTime overflow error in linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have a piece of code that tries to insert a date into a database using linq to sql.

```
 rec.CreationDateTime =System.DateTime.Now;
```

This line throws the exception

> " SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM"

I have read the different solutions suggested online. What i don't understand is how `System.DateTime.Now` can be outside the range that would cause this exception.

`System.DateTime.Now` is certainly far above anywhere near "1753". Likewise the year "9999" is quite some way ahead of 2015.

Can someone enlighten me on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any other DateTime field in your table?

Comment: no. Why would that matter?

Comment: default value for DateTime in .Net is DateTime.MinValue which is 01/01/0001. If there was another DateTime column in your table, it might not have been set a value from your code, so it automatically gets DateTime.MinValue as its value which results in the same exception

Comment: It would seem that there is some `DateTime` column that you're trying to insert `NULL` into (or e.g. the result of an empty string being converted to a `DateTime`). FInd that `DateTime`, fix it to have a proper value for SQL Server - done. Or change the SQL Server datatype to `DATETIME2(3)` to avoid these issues altogether (SQL Server **2008** and newer)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I will double check my code and come back. many thanks to both of you for your help

Comment: Seems your `DateTime.Now` is lost later on *or* there is another `DateTime` property that is left un-assigned which is translated to default value of 01-01-0001 and that usually throws SQL exception